# How should I have reviewed a short question about a MySQL syntax error?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I was doing some first-post reviewing, and came across this question:

[What is wrong with this query I am new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267230/what-is-wrong-with-this-query-i-am-new)

Ignoring the "I am new" fluff in the title (it won't let me submit an edit for that), this question shouts "bad" at me, but I can't point at any individual part of the question that violates the SE rules:

It's understandable English. It has a clear question. It has enough code to trigger the syntax error being queried. I can't find an obvious dupe to point at after a few minutes of Googling.

I opted to skip in the end purely out of uncertainty, but would appreciate some guidance for the future.

Comment: "Ignoring the 'I am new' fluff in the title" Why do you want to ignore a problem with the question's title that you know should be fixed?

Comment: Because as I say in the question, it won't let me submit an edit for that. I know that part is a problem, but that problem is minor and grounds for an edit, not a flag.

Comment: Skip when you are unsure is a great thing to do, by the way :).

Comment: And the reason that it won't let you submit the edit is pointing out *another* problem with the question that you should fix, not telling you that you shouldn't fix anything with the question.  I didn't say that was grounds for a flag; it's grounds for editing the question, which is what you should be doing for posts in that queue that need editing.  It's not like the only thing you should do in FP is flag posts meriting flagging (although you should *also* do that).

Comment: Wow, that question has 2 edits already and both users ignored the title oO.

Comment: Should be closed as "typographical error to which the answer will never help anyone, not even the OP because it will just lead them (further?) down the path of not even bothering to try to solve their own problems".

Comment: @Servy I guess it's a poor choice of phrasing. My reason for asking this question is guidance on what I should have done when reviewing this question, as the question just _feels_ wrong to me. Since I knew that title change was needed, but was blocked by the system, people focusing on it is not valuable feedback for me.

Comment: @Scoots So you know that the title is bad, and needs to be fixed, but you didn't want to fix it, or discuss the fact that the title is bad and needs to be fixed in a question about what's wrong with the question?  Again, you should *actually fix the title* given that you know that it's wrong and you're trying to review the post from a queue, rather than just pretending that the title isn't actually awful.  The fact that your edited title is being rejected by the system as being an inappropriate title merely tells you that you *haven't yet succeeded in turning the title into a good title*.

Comment: @Servy You make a good point. The initial thought process I had was "Has fluff. Fluff is bad. Remove fluff". A better reaction would have been "even wthout fluff, title is bad as it provides almost no insight to the question, improve title". Thanks for perservering with me.

Comment: Then somebody fixes the title and introduces a blatant typo, "sytnax error". Classic :)